# Issue finding OpenGL header files in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl

I am currently trying to link the OpenGL library with my xcode project. I am not sure what I am missing when it comes to linking the file.

I have just recently added the OpenGL framework to my project in both framework sections. I have added a flag for the linker (-framework OpenGL). I have attempted to change the include path, search paths (for both library and header).

[image: code]
Here is the error I am getting. The chai3d comment says that I should use OpenGL 2.1, however I have no idea how to get this framework. I mainly want to try to get my current version of OpenGL linked.

I have the framework linked at least here, and also in the other Frameworks folder above.

[image: frameworks]

Here is what I did in the Linking section of the project settings (For both chai3d and libchai3d, as well as any of the other .xcodeproj files).

[image: linker]

I have also gone to build phases and moved around the frameworks to make sure that the OpenGL framework is before the file that generates the header not found error.

The error is shown as a "Lexical or Preprocessor Issue" > 'OpenGL/gl.h' File Not Found

Comment: This isn't a linking error. The compilation fails because the compiler can't find the specified file. Take a good look at your include path setting.

Comment: @john Well right now the file that I am attempting to locate is included in a framework that the project should be using. I checked to make sure that the file was actually there and it is. I'm just not sure how I can force the file to be seen by the project.
My possible workaround I might try is taking all of the files from my OpenGL framework and make a new folder with them in it. Then I can try to have a path like you said go to them there. But I am not sure if that would work.

Comment: Sorry but I'm no expert on MacOS. But several things could be wrong. I wouldn't try random measures to workaround the problem. I would try and understand the problem. You've set something up incorrectly, unfortunately even if I was a MacOS expert I don't think you've provided enough information to solve it.

Comment: For instance this page https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Installation/Mac says that you should add OpenGL to the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section. Have you done that? You don't say so in so many words above.

Comment: Add the path to the framework at `Search paths -> Framework Search Paths`. For OGL > 3.0 use `#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>`. Apple provides all OGL stuff on its own, no `glew` or similar is needed.

Comment: @Ripi2 Thanks! For my solution I ended up just using $(PROJECT_DIR) in the Framework Search path and recursion to find it. Whenever I had a direct line to the folder then it was not working. You should have your comment as a response because this helped fix my issue with the frameworks.